# Send request and get response in Jquery with autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, request

I am trying to **send request with values `Pubid:1, pubdate:"2021-02-14"`** but nothing working also after sending req, when response get I am trying to fetch data and run **jquery autocomplete** on response.

for reference please check my [interface](https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/index.php) and click on **Headline textbox** I am iimplementing in Headline textbox

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">Headline</label>
    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" id="head">
</div>

$( "#head" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/articlelist.php",
            data: {term:request.term,Pubid:"1",pubdate:"2021-02-14"},
            success: response,
            dataType: 'json',
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 100
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. Without any debugging information there's hundreds of reasons an AJAX request may be failing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ooops, thanks for the upgrade in knowledge :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have attached my project url there is not a single error also for now only  I have posted my data in console.log

Comment: I would guess that the format of the response is not in the format that autocomplete requires. Unfortunately without any debugging information it's going to be almost impossible to offer any useful help.

Comment: Could you please help me to send the response `https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/articlelist.php?Pubid=1&pubdate="2021-02-14"` in this formate where **Pubid=1&pubdate="2021-02-14"** are my parameter to send

Comment: If that's how the data needs to be sent then you should change POST to GET

Comment: Not working thank you I appreciate your help.